# how to convert letters into array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i am trying to convert letters into array.

All the letters are coming from mysql results randomly

```
    for($column=0;$column<8;$column++){
        echo '<div class="'.bluexyz.'">'.
        $field1 = mysql_fetch_object($sql)->code
.'</div>';
}
```

each individual letter is a div named bluexyz.

now i want to convert these letters into array.

i have used explode inside the forloop which is not working.

```
$array = explode('\n',$field1);
```

it is placing all the letters in the array index of [0]. i want to place a one letter in the one index.

Comment: [str_split](http://php.net/str_split)

Answer (score 1):

It'd be easier if you provide a clearer explanation and provide an example of what you're fetching and what exactly you're expecting the output to be.

From what I understand, you're trying to convert the $field1 string into array.

You could use [str_split() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) here.

Try this:

```
$array = str_split($field1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to do like this 
if the records are in :- a , b , c , d ,e ,f 
$array[0]=a;
$array[1]=b,
$array[2]=c

and so on

Comment: You mean is it like a string containing all these? Something like $str = "a , b , c , d ,e ,f " ??

Comment: yes and then place the $str into the array but you see it is inside the div.

each individual letter is inside the div and now i want to place in the array